# Prevent PowerCommands from removing System.Linq when removing and sorting usings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powercommands

I use PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010 http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99.  One feature which I like is the remove and sort using statements on save feature.  However it's also slightly irritating because it removes the using statement for System.Linq which cannot be automatically added back in with a CTRL + "." key combo.

Does anyone know either a way to hack PowerCommands to prevent it removing a specific using statement, or even better a way to enhance Visual Studio to resolve known extension methods in referenced assemblies such as System.Linq?